# How to use null||d.AM_Answer for select query

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm getting data from database and using union for joining 2 table. But I need to use `null || d.AM_Answer`. Here I'm using only `null, null`. But it's taking only `null` value coming. If I stored the answer, I'm not getting answer. So, I need to use `null || d.AM_Answer`.

```
select
    b.QM_ID, b.QM_QCM_ID, b.QM_Question, b.QM_Type, b.QM_Parent_Id, null, null 
from 
    question_master b 
    INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
     on ( d. AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id 
          AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
          AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
          and d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@ )
```

Comment: I see no use of `UNION` in there?

Comment: I didn't mention here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifnull` to check if a field is null or not. If not null, then use field value.

***Example***:

```
IFNULL( d.AM_Answer, null )
```

This returns value of `d.AM_Answer` if it is not null.

And, you have some errors in your value comparison statements.

```
AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@
```

If `%d` and `%@` are place holders for numerics, then it is wrong way of input.
For runtime value inputs, you have to use `?` place holder and use prepared statements to bind values on those parameters.

```
AND d.AM_HNM_ID = ? 
AND d.AM_HM_ID = ?
AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = ?
```

Use your server side scripting language for value binding.

***Refer to***:

- [***MySQL: IFNULL(expr1,expr2)***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)